# Exchange 2010 to Exchange 2010 migration, mail flow problems

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010, exchange-migration

I currently have Exchange Server 2010 SP3 RU8 v2 installed on a primary DC which is Windows Server 2008 R2, I know this is less than ideal so I've setup another server also 2008 R2 on the domain. My current exchange server has all the roles installed (Mailbox, Hub Transport and Client Access).

I installed the identical version of Exchange on a new domain server (also Server 2008 R2) with all the same roles with the intention of moving the mailboxes slowly over the next week or so and retiring exchange on the DC.

Unfortunately, this has caused me several issues with mail flow.

The first being that I had a transport rule setup on the existing server which allowed 'anonymous access' for one of are internal application to send messages. This caused issues with the exchange server(s) not being able to authenticate with each other and emails stopped functioning. I resolved that by removing my internal network from that rule which then broke the anonymous relay so I setup another rule specifically for that application using a port other than 25 since I have the ability in the application to specify the port used.

Everything seemed okay as emails outbound and inbound were arriving at their destination. That was until this morning when I received word from several people in external domains that were receiving the following NDR:

Remote Server returned '<******.*** #5.7.1 smtp; 554 5.7.1 : Relay access denied>'

The issue seems to have been resolved by disabling the transport rules on the new server that were created during the installation.

My question is, what is the best way to slowly move things over to the new Exchange server without causing anymore trouble than I already have? My goal is to have all of my exchange roles and mailboxes on the new server and then completely remove exchange from the existing server.

I've tried to include as much information as possible but if I've left anything out that would be important to the resolution, please let me know and thank you all in advance!!